# the faster way to move pivot or origin in object mode

Tags: snapping, origin

[image]

Pls see the image, It should be simple :

In object mode, i want to move the pivot (transform handle) to the other end of the curve. I'm thinking this should be done by simply drag the axis (transform handle) and snap it to the other end. Seems that's no way i can drag only the origin/pivot.

The only thing i can do is to go to edit mode, select the target vertex, move 3 cursor to jump to that point. go back to object mode and then move to origin to the 3d cursor. Seriously, how can i do it in a simple way ?

Comment: you don't have to move the origin to move the pivot point, you can designate the 3D cursor as the pivot point in the Pivot point menu, but maybe I don't understand what you want

Comment: Thanks for reply , For example : I want to snap the curve so the other end point of the curve  will snap to a center of a cylinder top.

Comment: oh ok, well it should work, for example if I try with cubes it works, I don't know why it doesn't with a simple mesh